# Prefix every column name with a specific string?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to *manually* map some rows to instances of their appropriate classes. I know that I need to use every column of every table, and map all of those columns from one table into a given class.

However, I was wondering if there would be an easier way to do it. Right now, I have a class called `School` and a class called `User`. Each of these classes has a `Name` property, and other properties (but the ´Name` one is the important one, since it is a mutual name for both classes).

Right now, I am doing the following to map them down.

`SELECT u.SomeOtherColumn, u.Name AS userName, s.SomeOtherColumn, s.Name AS schoolName FROM User AS u INNER JOIN School AS s ON something`

I would love to do the following, but I can't, since `Name` is a mutual name between the classes.

`SELECT u.*, s.* FROM User AS u INNER JOIN School AS s ON something`

This however generates an error since they both have the column `Name`. Can I prefix them somehow? Like this for instance?

`u.user_*, s.school_*`

So that every column of each of those tables have a prefix? For instance `user_Name` and `school_Name`?

Comment: I would say the right answer here is what you have in the question: "Right now, I am doing the following to map them down..."

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL, retrieving the column names from the `information_schema.tables` view or similar, and build a `SELECT` statement and execute. I wouldn't recommend it, just saying you could if you really wanted to.

Comment: What I would suggest is to find an ORM that does the work for you, like Entity Framework. I know you said you want to do it manually, but if you can give up that need, an ORM definitely makes life a lot easier.

Comment: @JoeEnos how does `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` help solve the actual problem? The metadata is going to return two instances of the column `Name`, and the OP still has to provide an alias for at least one of them to avoid collisions. Also I disagree that an ORM is the magic solution needed here either.

Comment: I agree with @MarcGravell - you're already doing this the right way. Searching for a workaround [that allows you to use SELECT * is doing it wrong](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx).

Comment: The thing is, I am often selecting users in a statement that also joins other tables. And then I use a function called BuildUser on the rows returned. This makes it necessary for me to name all columns the same always, since this method looks for those exact keys.

Comment: And there is why I use dbo.School.SchoolName and dbo.User.UserName ..

Comment: @granadaCoder will that also return those names when enumerating the columns?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Building a dynamic query - with the column names (from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`), loop through each of the columns for table1, and append `table1.{colname} as table1_{colname},` to the `select` statement that you're dynamically building, and repeat for all tables. Again, I wouldn't do it, but it does meet the requirements.

Comment: @Joe my point was your comment was hardly enough information to even get to your second comment, never mind an actual solution. :-\

Comment: As others have pointed out, `SELECT *` is evil, avoid that if you can. There is nothing wrong with this syntax: `SELECT u.SomeOtherColumn FROM User u`.

Comment: One of the advantages of explicitly listing all of the selected columns, instead of using `*`, is that you are guaranteed to get those, and only those, columns and in that order. If the tables you're querying ever change, that could insulate your query from the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years ago I wrote a bunch of functions and procedures to help me with developing automatic code-generation routines for SQL Servers and applications using dynamic SQL.  Here is the one that I think would be most helpful to your situation:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[ColumnString2]
(
    @TableName  As SYSNAME,       --table or view whose column names you want
    @Template   As NVarchar(MAX), --replaces '{c}' with the name for every column,
    @Between    As NVarchar(MAX)  --puts this string between every column string
)   
    RETURNS NVarchar(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str As NVarchar(MAX);

    SELECT  TOP 999
        @str = COALESCE(
                @str + @Between + REPLACE(@Template,N'{c}',COLUMN_NAME), 
                REPLACE(@Template,N'{c}',COLUMN_NAME)
                        )
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA= COALESCE(PARSENAME(@TableName, 2), N'dbo')
      And   TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

    RETURN @str;
END
```

This allows you to format all of the column names of a table or view any way that you want.  Simply pass it a table name, and a Template string with *'{c}'* everywhere that you want the column name inserted for each column.  It will do this for every column in `@TableName`, and add the `@Between` string in between them.

Here is an example of how to vertically format all of the column names for a table, renaming them with a prefix in a way that is suitable for inclusion into a SELECT query:

```
SELECT dbo.[ColumnString2](N'yourTable', N'
    {c} As prefix_{c}', N',')
```

This function was intended for use with dynamic SQL, but you can use it too by executing it in Management Studio with your output set to Text (instead of Grid).  Then cut and paste the output into your desired query, view or code text. (Be sure to change your SSMS Query options for Text Results to raise the "*maximum number of characters displayed*" from 256 to the max (8000).  If that still gets cut off for you, then you can change this procedure to a function that outputs each column as a separate row, instead of as one single large string.)